# ssh stopped working due to roaming

Tags: networking, server, ssh

I've got an openssh sshd/client installed on my laptop, but I can't connect to any servers from this machine. whenever I try to, it just hangs like so: http://paste.pound-python.org/show/EO0b62Bq8gSQRewe27T4/ I've tried this: https://superuser.com/questions/326813/openssh-server-refuses-to-accept-key-authentication but it has yet to work. any help?

Comment: On the server does the file /etc/ssh/sshd_config set HostbasedAuthentication  to Yes?

Comment: Yeah. I did that too

Comment: can you provide sshd server logs with `LogLevel DEBUG3` ... this usually provides more useful information.